# SwiftUI – @State vs @Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, data-binding, observable, swift-property-wrapper

I am learning iOS Programming with Swift and SwiftUI. I know very little and I am very confused about the difference between a `@State` and a `@Binding`.

If I understood it correctly, `@Binding` is just technically `@State` but it doesn't update the view. If that is the case then why would I need `@Binding` if I could just use `@State` to do the same thing?

Comment: I used to think that all property wrappers are Bindings or something that's 100% observable. That's totally wrong. It just so happens that `@Bindable`'s property wrapper is one that allows you to observe changes to some other variable. However a different property wrapper like [Capitalized](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/) isn't observable and instead just makes the property capitalized.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

SwiftUI is a declarative Component-Oriented framework. You have to forget about MVC where you have controllers mediating between view and model. SwiftUI uses diffing algorithm to understand changes and update only corresponding views.

**@State**

- A State property is connected to the view. A State property is    permanently being read by the view. That means that every time the    @State property gets changed/updated, the view gets re-rendered and    eventually displays the content depending on the @State's data.
- State    is accessible only to a particular view.
- Simple properties like    strings, integers and booleans belongs to a single view - mark as    private.
- All the fields marked as State are stored in special    separated memory, where only corresponded view can access and update    them.

**@Binding**

- BindableObject protocol, which requires a didChange property. It makes possible to use it inside Environment and rebuild view as soon as it changes.
- The didChange property should be a Publisher, which is a part of a new Apple’s Reactive framework called Combine.
- The main goal of Publisher is to notify all subscribers when something changes. As soon as new values appear, SwiftUI will rebuild Views.

**@EnvironmentObject**

- It is a part of feature called Environment. You can populate your Environment with all needed service classes and then access them from any view inside that Environment.
- @EnvironmentObject is accessible for every view inside the Environment.
- @EnvironmentObject Properties created elsewhere such as shared data. App crashes if it is missing.
- The Environment is the right way of Dependency Injection with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 57):

Both `@State` and `@Binding` are property wrappers.

***@State***

- It is used to update the value of a variable every time.
- We can also say it's a two way binding.
- If we change the property state then SwiftUI will automatically reload the body of the view.
- It is used for simple properties like strings, integers and booleans.

***@Binding***

- Using this, you can access the state property of another view.
- It will give you the read and write access for the variable.

Comment: if I have a custom type that is a property in my view that can be updated by the user, is it bad practice to use @State on that property?

Answer (score 45):

Think of `State` as the single source of truth for your view, as a means of mutating a variable & invalidating the view to reflect that state.

`Binding` on the other hand, is [a two-way connection between a view and its underlying model](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding).
A means of mutating a `State` that is not managed by the view (for example a `Toggle` that reflects and controls a bool value that the control itself has no knowledge about its storage or origin)

Finally, you can get a `Binding` from any `State` by using the `$` prefix operator.

A simple guide for choosing between them would be:

- Do I need to modify a value that is **private** to me? --> **State**
- Do I need to modify a State of some **other view**? --> **Binding**

Answer (score 35):

### About @State and @Binding

Imagine a situation where you have two SwiftUI views. In the first view you have declared a `count` property, and in the second one, you have created a `Tap Me` button. When the button is tapped, the value of `count` in the first view should be updated. To implement this logic, you need a `@State` property wrapper in the first view and a `@Binding` property wrapper in the second one.

`@State` allows locally manipulate small amounts of data of `value type`. `@State` creates and manages values directly, so it's a `Source of Truth`. `@Binding` also refers to data of `value type` but owned by a different view. `@Binding` is not a source of truth. In order to feed the `@State` property to `Binding<T>` you need to use the `$` operator (i.e. it'll look like `$count`). `@Binding` creates a two-way connection between a property and another view.

Here's the code:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    
    @State private var count: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                SecondView(counter: $count).frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                Text("Tapped \(count) times").foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
                        
struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            Text("Tap Me").onTapGesture { counter += 1 }
        }
    }
}
```

Besides the aforementioned property wrappers, a similar result can be achieved with the help of so-called "trinity"-kit – `@StateObject`, `@Published` and `@ObservedObject`.

### Property Wrappers

The following pivot table represents three main characteristics (Source of Truth, purpose and semantics) of 20 commonly used SwiftUI property wrappers.

---

| # | Property Wrapper | Source of Truth | What it's for? | Semantics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | @AppStorage | Yes | reads/writes from UserDefaults | value |
| 02 | @Binding | no | creates a two-way connection | value |
| 03 | @Environment | no | reads data from the system | value |
| 04 | @EnvironmentObject | no | reads a shared object from multiple views | reference |
| 05 | @FetchRequest | Yes | use it for CoreData fetch request | value |
| 06 | @FocusedBinding | no | observing & unwrapping state bindings from the focused view | value |
| 07 | @FocusedValue | no | simpler version of @FocusedBinding | value |
| 08 | @GestureState | Yes | stores values of active gesture | value |
| 09 | @Namespace | Yes | is a wrapper for namespace.id that prevents name collision | value |
| 10 | @ObservedObject | no | refers to instance of external class that conforms to ObservableObject | reference |
| 11 | @Published | Yes | is attached to properties inside ObservableObject | value |
| 12 | @ScaledMetric | Yes | allow app views to scale given user's Dynamic Type settings | value |
| 13 | @SceneStorage | Yes | restores system state's lightweight data | value |
| 14 | @State | Yes | manipulates view's data locally | value |
| 15 | @StateObject | Yes | stores a new instance that conforms to ObservableObject | reference |
| 16 | @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor | Yes | creates an AppKit app delegate | protocol |
| 17 | @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor | Yes | creates an UIKit app delegate | protocol |
| 18 | [@Observable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) | it's macro | an iOS 17 replacement for ObservableObject + @Published + @ObservedObject pattern | reference |
| 19 | @Query | it's macro | reads Destination objects managed by SwiftData | reference |
| 20 | @Model | it's macro | makes a class load and store from SwiftData | reference |

### How to...

The following are examples of how you can use four popular property wrappers.

- [@Published + @ObservedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548432/swiftui-how-to-make-a-start-stop-timer/74317779#74317779)
- [@AppStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562534/swiftui-what-is-appstorage-property-wrapper/73321968#73321968)
- [@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516105/customizing-the-apps-main-menu-in-swiftui-environment/73517267#73517267)

Answer (score 13):

**State**

- `@State` keyword allows us to ask the SwiftUI to monitor the value of the property. Once the value will change, the `View` will be invalidated and rendered again in efficient manner.
- A persistent value of a given type, through which a view reads and monitors the value.
- It is just another `@propertyWrapper` that outlines a source of truth.
- When you use state the framework allocate persistence storage for variable and tracks it as a dependency ... you alway has to specify an initial constant value

**Binding**

- `@Binding` and `$`-prefix allows passing `State` property into the nested child.
- A manager for a value that provides a way to mutate it.
- `@Binding` yet another `@propertyWrapper` that depends explicitly on state.
- By using the `Binding` property wrapper you define an explicit dependency to a source of truth without owning it, additionally you don't need to specify an initial value because binding can be derived from state.

Link for your reference: [Medium](https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/swiftui-101-how-to-use-state-and-binding-in-your-first-custom-ui-control-64d395947492)

Answer (score 10):

I want to offer a *really short* 'real use' explanation, which helped me clear it out.
I'm not defining the State/Binding, I'm only pointing out the big difference.

### `@State` holds value, the 'source of truth'

### `@Binding` pass value, use as a pipeline.

One important thing regarding **@State**: Change will trigger a redraw. Changing the value of **@State** will cause the whole view to 're-execute'.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the notes I have prepared for myself,

**@State:**

- We need to use this inside a view struct
- It’s recommended to make as *private*
- We should *provide default* value
- Can be used as binding
- This is meant to store simple types like *String*, *Int*, *Bool*, etc...

**@Binding:**

- This is used to share common data between the views
- Best example is, presenting an sheet from View 1 and initiating dismiss action from View 2
- *No need for default value* as will set it from another view

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**State**
simple properties like string, integers, and Booleans Belong to a single view - mark as private

**Binding**
complex properties like custom type Sharing data in many views. Required for reference types

**EnvironmentObject**
properties created elsewhere such as shared data App crashes if it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 simple heuristics to decide when to use `@State` or `@Binding`:

1. A **single view** redraws when it changes state:

- View manages it's own `@State` variable

2. A **child view** redraws when it's **parent view** changes state:

`@State` -> `@Binding`

- Parent manages `@State`
- Parent passes `@State` to child via constructor
- Child keeps `@Binding` to passively track changes to `@State`

3. One or more **grandchild views** redraw when changes are made up the hierarchy:

`@ StateObject`  <-> `@ EnvironmentObject`

- Top level view manages `@StateObject`
- `@StateObject` is passed to highest ancestor view via `.environmentObject()`
- All child/grandchild views store their own reference vis `@EnvironmentObject`

Use `@StateObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` so you can share data directly with grandchildren, these wrappers are equivalent to `@State` and `@Binding` but allow you to skip children