# SwiftUI: What is @AppStorage property wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults

I used to save important App data like login credentials into UserDefaults using the following statement:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("sample@email.com", forKey: "emailAddress")
```

Now, I have come to know SwiftUI has introduced new property wrapper called:

> @AppStorage

Could anyone please explain how the new feature works?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### AppStorage

`@AppStorage` is a convenient way to save and read variables from UserDefaults and use them in the same way as `@State` properties. It can be seen as a `@State` property which is automatically saved to (and read from) `UserDefaults`.

You can think of the following:

```
@AppStorage("emailAddress") var emailAddress: String = "sample@email.com"
```

as an equivalent of this (which is *not* allowed in SwiftUI and will *not* compile):

```
@State var emailAddress: String = "sample@email.com" {
    get {
        UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "emailAddress")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "emailAddress")
    }
}
```

Note that `@AppStorage` behaves like a `@State`: a change to its value will invalidate and redraw a View.

By default `@AppStorage` will use `UserDefaults.standard`. However, you can specify your own `UserDefaults` store:

```
@AppStorage("emailAddress", store: UserDefaults(...)) ...
```

---

#### Unsupported types (e.g., `Array`):

As mentioned in iOSDevil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62849282/8697793), `AppStorage` is currently of limited use:

> types you can use in @AppStorage are (currently) limited to: Bool, Int, Double, String, URL, Data

If you want to use any other type (like `Array`), you can add conformance to `RawRepresentable`:

```
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("itemsInt") var itemsInt = [1, 2, 3]
    @AppStorage("itemsBool") var itemsBool = [true, false, true]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("itemsInt: \(String(describing: itemsInt))")
            Text("itemsBool: \(String(describing: itemsBool))")
            Button("Add item") {
                itemsInt.append(Int.random(in: 1...10))
                itemsBool.append(Int.random(in: 1...10).isMultiple(of: 2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Useful links:

- [What is the @AppStorage property wrapper?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper)
- [AppStorage Property Wrapper SwiftUI](https://medium.com/@ruchish7187/appstorage-property-wrapper-swiftui-c4ceba7ff5e7)

Comment: Do you know if `@AppStorage` reads from disk every time the containing View struct is created?

Comment: @malhal Unfortunately I don't know, I couldn't find enough documentation for it. But I'd imagine that UserDefaults are somehow observed and AppStorage is notified to reload when changes are detected. So it might not be read from disk when a view is redrawn. But it's just a guess.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll run some tests to figure it out. The reason I ask is I noticed that @FetchRequest hits the DB every time the View is created which is a big problem.

Comment: Nice answer! I've tried to **[re-implement it for using it in iOS 13 and UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64619591/5623035)**.

Comment: How can this be adapted to work with Dictionaries [:], e.g. [Int:Int]?

Comment: From my experiments so far the variable underlying a @AppStorage declaration is read from UserDefaults only once. E.g., if you define it in at the start of a class (along with instance variables), the value only gets read from UserDefaults when the instance is instantiated.

Answer (score 9):

Disclaimer: iOS 14 Beta 2

In addition to the other useful answers, the types you can use in @AppStorage are (currently) limited to: Bool, Int, Double, String, URL, Data

Attempting to use other types (such as Array) results in the error: "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: Do you know if arrays will be added in the coming betas or do you know any workaround to save an array?

Comment: @Lilfaen you can encode your array into a string representation e.g. with JsonEncoder().

Comment: @Lilfaen I added an example of how to save an `Array` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563773/8697793)

Answer (score 8):

## Re-implementation for iOS 13 and without SwiftUI

In additon to pawello2222 answer, here. is the reimplementation of the AppStorage that I named it as `UserDefaultStorage`:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefaultStorage<T: Codable> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T

    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

    init(key: String, default: T, store: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = `default`
        self.userDefaults = store
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: key) else {
                return defaultValue
            }
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            userDefaults.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

This wrapper can store/restore **any kind of codable** into/from the user defaults. Also, it works in iOS 13 and it **doesn't** need to import `SwiftUI`.

#### Usage

```
@UserDefaultStorage(key: "myCustomKey", default: 0)
var myValue: Int
```

**Note that** it can't be used directly as a `State`

Comment: I know you mentioned it can't currently be used as a `@State` but maybe you can make it a `DynamicProperty` somehow? So it behaves like a `@State`? (That'd be perfect).

Comment: I'm working on it :) it will have some unnecessary complications I think. But I will try :) @pawello2222

Answer (score 2):

This is a persistent storage provided by SwiftUI. This code will persist the email across app launches.

```
struct AppStorageView: View {
    @AppStorage("emailAddress") var emailAddress = "initial@hey.com"
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email Address", text: $emailAddress)
    }
}
```

With pure SwiftUI code, we can now persist such data without using `UserDefaults` at all.

But if you do want to access the underlying data, it is no secret that the wrapper is using `UserDefaults`. For example, you can still update using `UserDefaults.standard.set(...)`, and the benefit is that AppStorage observes the store, and the SwiftUI view will update automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`@AppStorage` property wrapper is a `source of truth` that allows you read data from and write it to `UserDefaults`. It has a value semantics. You can use `@AppStorage` to store any basic data type (like preferences' values or any default values) for as long as the app is installed.

For the best performance, when working with `UserDefaults`, you should keep the size of the stored data between 512 KB and 1 MB.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @AppStorage("t_101") var t_101: String = "Terminator T-101"
    @AppStorage("t_1000", store: .standard) var t_1000 = "Liquid Metal"
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hey, \(t_101)!").foregroundColor(.indigo)
            Text("Hey, \(t_1000)!").foregroundColor(.teal)

            Divider()

            Button("Real Names") {
                t_101 = "Arnie"
                t_1000 = "Robbie"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can test this via simple approach:

```
struct Content: View {
    
    private enum Keys {
    
        static let numberOne = "myKey"
    }
    
    @AppStorage(Keys.numberOne) var keyValue2: String = "no value"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                keyValue2 = "Hello"
                print(
                    UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Keys.numberOne) as! String
                )
            } label: {
                Text("Update")
            }
            
            Text(keyValue2)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented a behavior that I want to share with you. I had a View (called MainView) that used an @AppStorage Bool to display or not a message to users. In this View, I also had many views displaying data loaded from a JSON (cities).

I've developed a 'Add to favorite' feature that uses UserDefault to store a list of cities ID added by user in his/her favorites. The strange behavior was this one: As soon as user added or removed a city as favorite, all MainView's body (and all its child views) was updated. That means all content was reloaded for no reason.

After hours of investigations, specially refactoring all my ObservableObjects (models), my @Published variables and so on, I've find out what was creating this mass update: The @AppStorage in my MainView! As soon as you update any key in 'UserDefaults.standard' (in my case by storing my new favorite), all views's body using an @AppStorage are updated.

So @AppStorage is awesome and easy to use. But be aware of that behavior. You don't expect that a view is updated when you set a key that is not even used in that view!

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension on `Optional` to add support for persisting `Optional`s, all `Codable` types, `Date`s, arrays, dictionaries, etc. with `@AppStorage` or `@SceneStorage`:

```
extension Optional: RawRepresentable where Wrapped: Codable {
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "{}"
        }
        return json
    }

    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = value
    }
}
```

Here are some examples in action:

```
@AppStorage("recentCurrencies") var recentCurrencies: [String]? = nil
@SceneStorage("lastItem") var lastItem: SomeCodableType? = nil
@AppStorage("lastLaunch") var lastLaunch: Date? = nil
```

These generically persisted properties are optionals, so they need to be unwrapped in your code. For example:

```
var recentCurrencies = self.recentCurrencies ?? [] // unwrap
if !recentCurrencies.contains(code) {
    recentCurrencies.insert(code, at: 0)
}
self.recentCurrencies = Array(recentCurrencies.prefix(3)) // persist!
```