# How to Store Nested Arrays in @AppStorage for SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults, swiftui-list

`@AppStorage` was introduced in SwiftUI recently, it seems like an alternative to `UserDefaults`.
I'm trying to make the `@AppStorage` able to store nested lists.

For simple cases, you would do

```
@AppStorage("selected") var selected = 0
```

I used this while dealing with normal UserDefaults:

```
@Published var list = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "nestedList") as? [[String]] ?? [[String]]()
```

Long story short, how do I convert plain old `UserDefuaults` to the new property wrapper, `@AppStorage`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

All you need is to conform `Array` to `RawRepresentable` using the extension from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563773/8697793):

```
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("items") var items: [[String]] = [
        ["1", "2"],
        ["a", "b", "c"],
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("items: \(String(describing: items))")
            Button("Add item") {
                items[0].append(String(Int.random(in: 1...10)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SwiftUI 2.0** (Xcode 12 - maybe will be changed in future)

The `AppStorage` wrapper does not support containers now, only `Bool`, `Int`, `Double`, `String`, `URL`, `Data`.

[image]

So the solution for your case either to continue use `UserDefaults` or to encode/decode your nested array into JSON Data and use AppStorage with Data.

Comment: How do you use the standard user defaults in AppGroups? I’ve only done it in the AppStorage thing

Comment: UserDefaults does not depend on selected Life-Cycle, or platform or language, it is part of Foundation framework and it works the same everywhere available. [Just search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+UserDefaults)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Data to achieve this:

```
class Storage: NSObject {
    
    static func archiveStringArray(object : [String]) -> Data {
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            return data
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can't encode data: \(error)")
        }

    }

    static func loadStringArray(data: Data) -> [String] {
        do {
            guard let array = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [String] else {
                return []
            }
            return array
        } catch {
            fatalError("loadWStringArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
            
    @AppStorage("albums") var albums: Data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack {
                Text("AppStorage - array String")
                List {
                    ForEach (getStrings(data: albums), id:\.self) { s in
                        Text(s)
                    }
                }
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Text("read only")
                }
            VStack {
                Text("AppStorage - array String")
                List {
                    ForEach (getStrings(data: albums), id:\.self) { s in
                        Text(s)
                    }
                }
                Button("add album") {
                    addAlbum()
                }
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Text("add album")
                }
        }
    }
    
    func getStrings(data: Data) -> [String] {
        return Storage.loadStringArray(data: data)
    }
    func addAlbum() {
        var tmpAlbums = getStrings(data: albums)
        
        tmpAlbums.append("Album # \(tmpAlbums.count)")
        
        albums = Storage.archiveStringArray(object: tmpAlbums)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```