# onDelete with stored String Array

Tags: swiftui

I use Simone´s solution to store string arrays and present them in a List:

[How to Store Nested Arrays in @AppStorage for SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166706/how-to-store-nested-arrays-in-appstorage-for-swiftui)

I tried to add a row delete function to the List:

```
    .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
    
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        getStrings(data: albums).remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
```

I understand that this does not work because the function call returns an immutable value and I try to mutate it. How to resolve that?

Comment: Would you show all context code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following delete function. You first get all string, then remove at offset and then store it back.

```
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    var tmpAlbums = getStrings(data: albums)
    tmpAlbums.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    albums = Storage.archiveStringArray(object: tmpAlbums)
}
```