# How to loop over @AppStorage values and use them for creating TextFields?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to loop over @AppStorage variables and use them to create TextFields with predefined values. I've tried several things as adding and removing `$` for variable1-5 and variable, but nothing seems to work.

To make it easier I reduced the amount of variables and removed all the unneeded code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    static let store = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.not-important.etc")
    
    @AppStorage("variable1", store: store) var variable1 = "a"
    @AppStorage("variable2", store: store) var variable2 = "b"
    @AppStorage("variable3", store: store) var variable3 = "c"
    @AppStorage("variable4", store: store) var variable4 = "d"
    @AppStorage("variable5", store: store) var variable5 = "e"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form { 
                Section(header: Text("Variables")) {                    
                    HStack (alignment: .center) {
                        ForEach([
                            $variable1, // also tried variable1, etc...
                            $variable2,
                            $variable3,
                            $variable4,
                            $variable5
                        ], id: \.self) { variable in // also tried $variable
                            TextField(
                                "",
                                text: variable // also tried $variable, variable.wrappedName, variable.text, etc...
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help to understand what is the issue here and why I can not get it to work.

More info on errors here:

1. Provided example throws an error for `ForEach` line:
   `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'Hashable'`
2. When trying `$variable in` instead of `variable in` I get:
   `Inferred projection type 'String' is not a property wrapper`
3. TextField("", text: $variable) throws:
   `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue with your attempts, is that you are trying to create
an array of `variables`, but an array does not accept that, it accepts values,
String, Int, custom types etc..., but not `variables`. This is why it does not "work".

Since you may have lots of `variables` that you want to process in a loop,
I suggest you use an array instead. This makes looping very easy,
as shown in this example code. You can still have other independent `variables` in your code.

Here is the example code, using the Array extension to easily store the array in `AppStorage`, from: [SwiftUI: What is @AppStorage property wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562534/swiftui-what-is-appstorage-property-wrapper/62563773#62563773)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static let store = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.not-important.etc")
    
    @AppStorage("arr", store: store) var arr: [String] = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Variables")) {
                HStack (alignment: .center) {
                    ForEach(arr.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        TextField("", text: $arr[index])
                            .border(.red) // <-- for testing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```