# Why isn't this simple SwiftUI view updated?

Tags: swiftui

I'm having problem understand why the "Car" isn't updating?

If I remove the @State inside the CarView, everything is updating as expected. However, the CarView need to have the @State variable in order to be updated.

Thanks

```
@Observable class Factory {
    var currentCar: Car?
}

struct Car {
    let title: String
    var milage: Int
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.milage = 0
    }
}

struct FactoryView: View {
    @State var factory = Factory()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let car = factory.currentCar {
                CarView(car: car)
            }
            
            Button("Change car") {
                factory.currentCar = Car(title: "BMW") // **** NOT WORKING ****
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .onAppear {
            factory.currentCar = .init(title: "Ford")
        }
    }
    
}

struct CarView: View {
    @State var car: Car
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(car.title). Milage: \(car.milage)")
            
            Button("Increase milage") {
                car.milage += 1
            }
        }
        .padding(30)
        .border(.red)
    }
}

#Preview {
    FactoryView()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CarView` has a `Car` as its `@State`. It will keep maintaining this state until its identity changes. `@State` is a *source of truth* - its value is not going to depend on what `factory.currentCar` is.

When `CarView` is first shown, `car` is the Ford. When you tap the button, the `CarView`'s *identity* does not change, so no new `CarView` is going to be created with the new car.

Here is a simpler example demonstrating this:

```
struct XView: View {
    @State var x = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Increase") {
            // nothing you do to x here can change YView's @State
            // unless you change YView's identity, forcing it to create a new YView
            x += 1
        }
        YView(y: x)
    }
    
}

struct YView: View {
    @State var y: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        // YView itself can change its own states
        Text("\(y)")
    }
}
```

If tapping the button *does* change `CarView`'s identity, for example if you set its `id` to `car.title`, then a new `CarView` will be created with the new source of truth.

Note that the increase milage button in `CarView` is not modifying `factory.currentCar.milage`. You've essentially given a copy of `factory.currentCar` to `CarView`, and whatever happens to that car is not related to `factory.currentCar`

That said, if you want to modify the milage of `factory.currentCar`, `car` shouldn't be a source of truth of `CarView`. Make it a binding instead,

```
@Binding var car: Car
```

then you can *bind* it to `factory.currentCar`:

```
if let carBinding = Binding($factory.currentCar) {
    CarView(car: carBinding)
}
```

Even if you *do* want to modify a car independent of `factory.currentCar`, `CarView.car` should still be a `Binding`, and you should keep "the car that you are modifying" as a `@State` of `FactoryView`, as opposed to giving the `CarView` a different identity every time.

Learn more about `@State` vs `@Binding` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59247183/5133585).

Comment: Thanks so much, very nice explanation! Got it :)

Comment: From your answer: “It will keep maintaining this state until its identity changes” so same identity but none-equal data means no update?

Comment: @WizardofKneup Correct. SwiftUI doesn't even care what you passed to the `CarView` initialiser if its identity did not change. It doesn't compare the new data with the old data to see if they are "equal". For more info about what "identity" means in this context, see [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).

Comment: @WizardofKneup I'll say this just in case: in [your case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77328014/5133585), since `EdgeViewSUI` doesn't modify its data, you don't need a `@Binding`. Just declare it as a `let`.

Comment: Now, that was a smart remark. Indeed, I don't need a State at all here if it doesn't check on being equal. It is data that is part of the layout engine. I will start by recreating it each time. Thanks!

Comment: and for all that wonder... the previous 2 comments were all related to a different question that got closed by Sweeper... for all the right reasons.

Comment: @WizardofKneup Just for the record, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77328014/5133585) wasn't closed by me.